# Java - Getting cookie value without escape characters

Tags: java, cookies, encoding

I guess this is duplicate. But could not found what I am loking for.

I have one Java Spring MVC web application runniong as server. I have another angularJS application running as client. In AngularJS I am setting some cookies, But the string values are encoded with special characters. It looks like this

```
id=20; name=%22myname%22
```

In my Controller I am getting the cookie value **id** properly, but not name.

```
Cookie[] cookies=request.getCookies();

String name=cookies[1].getValue();
System.out.println(name);
```

And it prints

**`%22myname%22`**

How to get rid of this encoded characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can decode your string in your controller as follows:

```
URLDecoder.decode(name, "utf8")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String value = URLDecode.decode(cookie.getValue(), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: I am not adding the cookie by Java. I am setting it by angularJS